# Pandas create new column if date/hour matches from another dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes. First has date/time and location, second has date and weather by the hour.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'date':['1/01/2001 0:20:15', '1/1/2001  1:10:55', '1/1/2001  2:05:31'],
        'location':[('x1','y1'),('x2','y2'),('x3','y3')]})

weather = pd.DataFrame({'date':['1/01/2001 0:00:00','1/01/2001 1:00','1/01/2001 2:00'],
           'condition':['snow','light snow','rain']})
```

I want to add a column 'condition' to data if the date and hour match
(ex 1/01/2001 0:20:15 matches 1/01/2001 0:00:00)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use `dt.hour` accessor in pandas to extract hours of date in two `DateFrame` and then `merge` on the hour match.

```
import pandas as pd
df_loc = pd.DataFrame(data)    # With mock location data
df_weather = pd.DataFrame(weather)

# Convert date from string to datetime type
df_loc['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_loc['date'])
df_weather['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_weather['date'])

# Extract hour
df_loc['hour'] = df_loc['date'].dt.hour
df_weather['hour'] = df_weather['date'].dt.hour

# Merge on hour match
df_loc_condition = df_loc.merge(df_weather[['hour', 'condition']], on=['hour'], 
                                how='left')
```

the result will be:

```
print(df_loc_condition)

    date                location   hour  condition
0   2001-01-01 00:20:15 (x1, y1)    0   snow
1   2001-01-01 01:10:55 (x2, y2)    1   light snow
2   2001-01-01 02:05:31 (x3, y3)    2   rain
```

Comment: That seemed to solve my problem! Thank you so much! It did create a bunch of duplicates but that was easy enough to remove.

Comment: If you have `date` from different dates, you can also create a `date_` column without the time by `.dt.date` accessor,  and then merge `on=['date_', 'hour']`. Which should solve the duplication problem. @Lee

Comment: Awesome! That fixes it 100%!